# Using a constructor to initilize pointers to NULL in a Double linked List

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to initialize a new object of a class Dlist. After a new object is declared the pointers **first** and **last** are supposed to be **NULL**. When I declare the Dlist **temp** first and last however- the constructor isn't being recognized and the compiler is giving them values like **0x0**. I'm not sure why the the constructor being recognized.

```
// dlist.h
class Dlist {
private:
// DATA MEMBERS
struct Node
{
    char data;
    Node *back;
    Node *next;
};

Node *first;
Node *last;

// PRIVATE FUNCTION
Node* get_node( Node* back_link, const char entry, Node* for_link );


public:

// CONSTRUCTOR
Dlist(){ first = NULL; last = NULL; }  // initialization of first and last 

// DESTRUCTOR
~Dlist();

// MODIFIER FUNCTIONS
void append( char entry);
bool empty();
void remove_last();

//CONSTANT FUNCTIONS
friend ostream& operator << ( ostream& out_s, Dlist dl);

};           
#endif

// implementation file
int main()
{
Dlist temp;
char ch;

cout << "Enter a line of characters; # => delete the last character." << endl
<< "-> ";


cin.get(ch);
temp.append(ch);

cout << temp;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand that NULL and 0x0 are the same value?

Comment: `0x0` means zero, which (usually) is the address used to represent null.

Comment: What do you mean constructor isn't recognized? You can't step into it in the debugger?

Comment: You aren't initializing the pointers, you're assigning to them.

Answer (score 1):

0x0 is NULL. Also, initialization of class members is more efficiently done via the constructor's initialization list:

```
Dlist()
    : first(nullptr)
    , last(nullptr)
{ /* No assignment necessary */ }
```

When a class is constructed, the initialization list is applied to the memory acquired for the object before the body of the constructor is executed.

Comment: Well, technically `NULL` is not required to *be* zero by the C specification -- though it is required to *compare equal* to 0.